# Mysql cut string, the first character?

Tags: mysql, string

Hi is it possible to cut string like this:

String in "data" columns: ,123,456

Cut the first character i.e "," (comma).

So the query is something like:

```
Update users set data = cut first string...
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`UPDATE users SET data = SUBSTR(data, 2);`

This will iterate through all rows in `users` and replace `data` with itself minus the first character.